By-products of cleaning glassware with chromic acid
Currently, my lab employs chromic/sulfuric acid bath to clean glassware. Currently, our baths are more brownish/green (but not yet green like chromium (III)), rather then deep orange when freshly prepared. However they are still pretty strong. Recently, after using the acid bath to clean some glassware, the next morning I opened the bath, only to be hit with an intense, irritating smell.
The glassware that I had placed in the bath could have had residual amounts of benzonitrile, methylene chloride, and tetrabutyl ammonium tetraboroflorate salt.
After realizing my mistake and discussing the incident with senior members, I know understand the importance of thoroughly pre-washing glassware. However, I was curious as to what could have possibly formed in the bath to create such a strong smell, as I have put tons of glassware in there with small amounts of insoluble organic matter, but have never experienced this before.
If I had to guess, I would assume any benzonitrile left over was oxidized into some amide or carboxylic acid. The methylene chloride most likely would’ve evaporated off, but if it were to be oxidized, (is this bath strong enough to do so?) it would create carbon dioxide/monoxide. Maybe phosgene? But I can’t imagine that would survive for very long either and would undergo further reactions.
Lastly, the ammonium salt, which I believe is the culprit, could have possibly make some ammonia based by-product. But my knowledge of inorganic chemistry is not solid enough to guess what.
My question:
Assuming the main contaminants were methylene chloride, benzonitrile, and tetrabutylammonium tetrafluoroborate; what are the possible by-products that could come out of cleaning the glassware in a chromic/sulfuric acid bath.

Dependent on thought, and subsequently the chemistry engaged, perhaps you/your group can retire chromic acid to clean glass ware for good. iPrOH/acetone, detergent and water, basic KOH/EtOH bath with ultrasound, bleach, piranha mix, etc (not necessarily in this sequence) can be alternatives before putting the beakers and flasks into the dishwasher.

No organic component can survive this bath and no one can predict what happened because one does not know the full history. Whatever the odor was, it must be inorganic vapors. Keep in mind this mixture is carcinogenic (known human carcinogen due to Cr(VI)). Find better and safer alternatives like the base bath as suggested above. Also, it is known that Cr can stick to glass. Heavy metal cleaning solutions should be given up.

@ACR the BF4 from the ammonium salt is the first and only inorganic compound to go on there. Are you suggesting that BF4 can possibly decompose in the acid bath? Tributyl amine seems like a very plausible answer but your saying that it wouldn’t survive in that bath?

@ACR  I understand the mixture is complex but all the other components would be at too low of a concentration in the bath to be the major product causing the smell. Additionally, the same smell came out of the flask that contained the salts when rinsed. It’s likely the smell originates from a reaction between the salt and acid

It seem like this is some volatile compound of chromium or nitrogen oxides. As stated earlier organic compounds cannot survive the bath, and and amines cannot escape acidic solutions. They exist as salts.

Do we know that the bath is still acidic?

@Waylander yes. It still reacts pretty violently with the sodium bicarb placed around it.

Not going to be tributylamine then as that will still be a salt in solution
